# Close tmux session with a particular name

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

I would like to have a command that closes all tmux session which name corresponds to a pattern. The pattern, in the language of regex, is `nn\d+`

I feel that I should be able to use a combination of grep and xargs.

I tried with
`tmux ls | grep -P "nn\d+" | ..`
but I am not sure how to use `xargs` here, that is: I am not sure how to refer to only the name part of the matched string, and to one string at the time.

To be more precise, the output of `tmux ls` is something like:

```
1: 1 windows (created Thu Mar 25 12:49:17 2021)
2: 1 windows (created Thu Mar 25 12:50:20 2021)
nn312133: 1 windows (created Thu Mar 25 12:53:54 2021)
nn3123: 1 windows (created Thu Mar 25 12:53:52 2021)
```

The output from grep is:

```
nn312133: 1 windows (created Thu Mar 25 12:53:54 2021)
nn3123: 1 windows (created Thu Mar 25 12:53:52 2021)
```

I should need to pipe `nn312133` and `nn3123` into `tmux kill-session -t $x`

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `tmux ls | grep -Po "nn\d+" | xargs -n1 tmux kill-session -t`

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -Po` to make grep only print out the matched part instead of the whole line.

Comment: Great! I ended up with this: `tmux ls | grep -Po "nn\d+" | xargs -I %  sh -c 'tmux kill-session -t %'` Please let me know if anyone can find a less verbose solution

Comment: or better yet `tmux ls | grep -Po "nn\d+" | xargs -n1 tmux kill-session -t `